# Добавить прокси в запросы aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp

Мой код:

```
connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True)
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector, headers=headers, trust_env=True) as session:
     async with session.post("https://site.ru", json=json_data) as resp:
          print(await resp.json())
```

Как мне установить прокси с авторизацией в запросы?

Comment: Обратитесь к методу aiohttp.ClientSession.request(method="POST", proxy="8.8.8.8", proxy_auth=aiohttp.BasicAuth(str, password=str, encoding='latin1'))

Comment: А куда логин вводить?

Comment: Перед password идёт login